# ¿Porqué el while no cumple la condición que le doy?

Tags: java, while

Es un programa para patear penales. El problema es que después de que cada equipo patea el primer penal, no siguen pateando y finaliza.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Penales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    String jugador1;
    String jugador2;
    int pateo=0;
    int goles1=0;
    int goles2=0;
    int tiros=0; 
System.out.println("Bienvenido al Simulador de Penales MMXVIII");
System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del equipo del 1º jugador:");
jugador1=entrada.next();
System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del equipo del 2º jugador:");
jugador2=entrada.next();
while((tiros<=10)&&(goles1!=goles2)){       
System.out.println("Patea "+jugador1);
System.out.println("A donde quieres patear: 1-Izquierda 2-Picarla 3-Derecha");
pateo=entrada.nextInt();
int direccion = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;
if (direccion==pateo) {
    tiros=tiros+1;
switch(pateo) {
case 1:

System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
System.out.println("|                                           |");
System.out.println("|                                           |");
System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
System.out.println("|       (ºº)                                |");
System.out.println("|       -()-                                |"); 
System.out.println("|        ||                                 |"); 
System.out.println("         O");
    break;
case 2:
        System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                    (ºº)                   |");
        System.out.println("|                    -()-                   |"); 
        System.out.println("|                     ||                    |"); 
        System.out.println("                      O");
            break;
case 3:
    System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
    System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
    System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                           |");
    System.out.println("|                                           |");
    System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                  (ºº)     |");
    System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                   ||      |"); 
    System.out.println("                                    O");
        break;
    }

}else if(direccion!=pateo) {
    tiros=tiros+1;
    goles1=goles1+1;

switch(pateo) {


case 1:
    System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
    System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
    System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
    System.out.println("|     O                                     |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                           |");
    System.out.println("|                                           |");
    System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                  (ºº)     |");
    System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                   ||      |"); 
        break;
case 2:
        System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                     O                     |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                  (ºº)     |");
        System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                   ||      |"); 
            break;
case 3:
            System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                     O     |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|       (ºº)                                |");
        System.out.println("|       -()-                                |"); 
        System.out.println("|        ||                                 |"); 
             break;
}
}
    System.out.println("Patea "+jugador2);
    System.out.println("A donde quieres patear: 1-Izquierda 2-Picarla 3-Derecha");
    pateo=entrada.nextInt();
    int direccion1 = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;
    if (direccion1==pateo) {
        tiros=tiros+1;
    switch (pateo) {
    case 1:
    System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
    System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
    System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                           |");
    System.out.println("|                                           |");
    System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
    System.out.println("|       (ºº)                                |");
    System.out.println("|       -()-                                |"); 
    System.out.println("|        ||                                 |"); 
    System.out.println("         O");
        break;
    case 2:
            System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                    (ºº)                   |");
        System.out.println("|                    -()-                   |"); 
        System.out.println("|                     ||                    |"); 
        System.out.println("                      O");
                break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                  (ºº)     |");
        System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                   ||      |"); 
        System.out.println("                                    O");
        break;
    }

    }else if(direccion1!=pateo) {
        tiros=tiros+1;
        goles2=goles2+1;
    switch (pateo) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|     O                                     |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                  (ºº)     |");
        System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                   ||      |"); 
            break;
            case 2:
            System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                                           |");
        System.out.println("|                     O                     |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                  (ºº)     |");
        System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |"); 
        System.out.println("|                                   ||      |"); 
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
    System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————————————————————┐");
    System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                     O     |"); 
    System.out.println("|                                           |");
    System.out.println("|                                           |");
    System.out.println("|                                           |"); 
    System.out.println("|       (ºº)                                |");
    System.out.println("|       -()-                                |"); 
    System.out.println("|        ||                                 |");
                    break;
    }

}
}
    }}
```

Comment: Está padre el programa, la condición no se cumple desde un inicio`(goles1!=goles2)`.

Comment: El problema es la condición while((tiros<=10)&&(goles1!=goles2)){ . Ya en la primera ejecución no debe entrar, porque goles1 vale 0 y goles2 vale 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es interesante y divertido tu programa, el primer problema que se ha destacado es que no ejecuta el código dentro de la sentencia `while` ya que `goles1` y `goles2` tienen el mismo valor

```
while((tiros<=10)&&(goles1!=goles2)){
```

No soy muy fan de futbol pero yo definiría una cantidad total de tiros las cuales deben cumplirse, por ejemplo `10` ya que me parece son las oportunidades que se tienen:

```
  int MAXIMA_CANT_TIROS = 10;
  while ((tiros <= MAXIMA_CANT_TIROS) /*&& (goles1 != goles2)*/) {
```

y también debemos suponer que debe haber un ganador, por lo tanto debemos permitir mas tiros hasta que ambos equipos dejen de estar empatados:

```
 while (tiros <= MAXIMA_CANT_TIROS || goles1 == goles2) {
```

de esta forma se realizará la [tanda de penalties](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanda_de_penaltis)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería el código con la modificación:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Penalties {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        String jugador1;
        String jugador2;
        int pateo = 0;
        int goles1 = 0;
        int goles2 = 0;
        int tiros = 0;
        int MAXIMA_CANT_TIROS = 10;
        System.out.println("Bienvenido al Simulador de Penales MMXVIII");
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del equipo del 1º jugador:");
        jugador1 = entrada.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del equipo del 2º jugador:");
        jugador2 = entrada.next();

        /*Se realizarán penalties hasta que se cumplan las condiciones:
        1)La cantidad de tiros totales:  tiros <= MAXIMA_CANT_TIROS
        2)El marcador NO se encuentre empatado: goles1 == goles2 */
        while (tiros <= MAXIMA_CANT_TIROS || goles1 == goles2 /*&& (goles1 != goles2)*/) {
            System.out.println("Marcador: " + jugador1 + " " + goles1 + " - " + jugador2 + " " + goles2);
            System.out.println("Patea " + jugador1);
            System.out.println("A donde quieres patear: 1-Izquierda 2-Picarla 3-Derecha");            
            pateo = entrada.nextInt();
            int direccion = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;
            if (direccion == pateo) {
                tiros = tiros + 1;
                switch (pateo) {
                    case 1:

                        System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|     (͡°͜ʖ͡°)                              |");
                        System.out.println("|       -()-                                |");
                        System.out.println("|        ||                                 |");
                        System.out.println("         O");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                  (͡~͜ʖ͡°)                 |");
                        System.out.println("|                    -()-                   |");
                        System.out.println("|                     ||                    |");
                        System.out.println("                      O");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                (͡°͜ʖ͡°)  |");
                        System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                   ||      |");
                        System.out.println("                                    O");
                        break;
                }

            } else if (direccion != pateo) {
                tiros = tiros + 1;
                goles1 = goles1 + 1;

                switch (pateo) {

                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|     O                                     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                (͠°͟ʖ͡°)   |");
                        System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                   ||      |");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                     O                     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                (͠°͟ʖ͡°)   |");
                        System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                   ||      |");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                     O     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|     (͠°͟ʖ͡°)                              |");
                        System.out.println("|       -()-                                |");
                        System.out.println("|        ||                                 |");
                        break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Marcador: " + jugador1 + " " + goles1 + " goles - " + jugador2 + " " + goles2);
            System.out.println("Patea " + jugador2);
            System.out.println("A donde quieres patear: 1-Izquierda 2-Picarla 3-Derecha");            
            pateo = entrada.nextInt();
            int direccion1 = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;
            if (direccion1 == pateo) {
                tiros = tiros + 1;
                switch (pateo) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
                        System.out.println("┌——————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|     (͡☉͜ʖ͡☉)                             |");
                        System.out.println("|       -()-                                |");
                        System.out.println("|        ||                                 |");
                        System.out.println("         O");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                 (͡☉͜ʖ͡☉)                 |");
                        System.out.println("|                    -()-                   |");
                        System.out.println("|                     ||                    |");
                        System.out.println("                      O");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("El arquero atajo el penal");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                (͡☉͜ʖ͡☉)  |");
                        System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                   ||      |");
                        System.out.println("                                    O");
                        break;
                }

            } else if (direccion1 != pateo) {
                tiros = tiros + 1;
                goles2 = goles2 + 1;
                switch (pateo) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|     O                                     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                               (͡☉͟ʖ͡☉)   |");
                        System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                   ||      |");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                     O                     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                (͡☉͟ʖ͡☉)  |");
                        System.out.println("|                                  -()-     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                   ||      |");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOL!!!");
                        System.out.println("┌———————————————————————————┐");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                     O     |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|                                           |");
                        System.out.println("|     (͡☉͟ʖ͡☉)                             |");
                        System.out.println("|       -()-                                |");
                        System.out.println("|        ||                                 |");
                        break;
                }

            }
        }

         System.out.println("    .-~\\@/~-.\n" +
"   /   _|_   \\\n" +
"  @\\__/a@a\\__/a\n" +
"  a/  \\_@_/  \\@\n" +
"   \\__/   \\__/\n" +
"    `a\\___/a'     Marcador final: " + jugador1 + " " + goles1 + " - " + jugador2 + " " + goles2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Solo una pregunta más, ¿Como hago para que si llegan a los 10 tiros y estan iguales de goles que c/u haga un tiro mas hasta desempatar?

Comment: Se que debe haber un campeón para eso agrega esa condición en el while :  while ((tiros <= MAXIMA_CANT_TIROS || goles1 == goles2)) { , terminaran los tiros cuando los goles de ambos equipos no sean los mismos,  modifico en la respuesta. @BrianB3

Comment: No te doy un beso en la frente porque no soy de Mexico!

Comment: Hehehe @BrianB3 me da gusto solucionaste tu problema, solo recuerda realizar las preguntas basandote en [ask] y te aseguro tendrás aún más respuestas, saludos!